# How to get the list of selected rows of a Gtk.TreeView as int?

Tags: python, treeview, pygtk, gtk3

I found that I can get the selected rows like this

```
model, iters = treeview.get_selection().get_selected()
```

or like this

```
model, paths = treeview.get_selection().get_selected_rows()
```

but `iters` and `paths` are not lists of `int`.

Is it possible to convert a `Gtk.TreeIter` or a `Gtk.TreePath` to `int`?

Comment: assuming that your treeview is displaying a listStore, then the path is a string which should also be the integer index into the store. If you are dipslaying a recursive data structure (like a folder hierarchy, then the path is more complex, and can't be converted easily into an int). The bigger question is - why do you need the list of ints - what do they signify ? Since data access into the ListStore (or a TreeStore) are via iters and paths (and not simple ints), it might be a better design to store the int that you want as part of each row, and extract the int when you get the selected rows

Comment: Well, what happens is that I'm not very good working with graphic interfaces and almost always I do what comes to my mind.As you said that paths are strings, I tried doing int(str(path)) and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: I am glad it worked - but do think about why you need the numbers. As with many things it is better to work with what you have been provided, rather than trying to force it to work the way you think you need it :-) Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [get_path](https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtktreemodel.html#method-gtktreemodel--get-path).

```
if iters is not None:
    row_number = model.get_path(iters)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use :
**path, _ = treeview.get_cursor()**
path is a 'TreePath' and not 'int'

**indices = path.get_indices()**
indices is a list of the row numbers :   [2 , ...]

**indices[0]** is the first row number (as integer !) of the selection